# How to have all the fields available in a display mode for content type D8

Tags: entities

I'd like to be able to choose the date field or other fields that you can see in form display in 'custom display mode' for content types ?

How can I do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like you’re asking for Display Suite + Display suite Extra fields, if you want to have Title, Authored On, etc fields on the display configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't find Display suite Extra fields... Does it have a new name for D8 ?

Comment: I haven't used it in D8, perhaps its just a config setting now inside of Display Suite. It exposes these fields to the display forms.

Comment: Couldn't find it....

Answer (score 0):

You need to drag the items that you don't want to the disabled section. This works for both form display and front end display.

[image: Hide Form options]

For your custom display mode, you should be able to select from each display mode:
[image: Select display mode]

Comment: Thank you, but it's not what I want to do. I want to add fields that I can see in form display in display mode.

Comment: It works the same in form display mode, @Anupriya_vij provided that screenshot (they look nearly identical, but are a different tab).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use Display suite and activate a layout in the display mode.

Answer (score -2):

You can go to admin/structure/types/manage/content_type/form-display and drag the fields under "disabled" which you don't want to show in the node edit form. Rest will be present in node edit form

But the field which you have moved under disabled, will show up in front end display.

Attached is the screen shot

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the same answer Matt posted 17 hours ago.

Comment: @Kevin No, actually this answer shows the _Manage form display_ tab, not the _Manage display_ one as the other answer.